# Android app how to properly load image thumbnails from web

Tags: android, sdk, loading, android-image

So i am trying to load a bunch of thumbnails (possibly up to 100+) from the web, and I seem to be running out of memory around 30 on the emulator, and around 80-85 on the phone itself.

This is not going to work but there has to be a way-

I even tried saving the images to cache memory and loading from there, but it still runs out of memory.

What is the correct way to load a lot of web thumbnail images?

each image is about 50 kb, im basically adding the imageViews dynamically through a method i made called CreateImage. This pretty much loads each thumbnail based on the URL and image name, and sets it in a dynamic imageView in a horizontalScollView.

```
    private void createImages(String URL, String imageName){
    ImageView ImageThumbnails = new ImageView(this);
    ImageThumbnails.setId(ImageThumbName);
    ImageThumbnails.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
    ImageThumbnails.getLayoutParams().height = 85;
    ImageThumbnails.getLayoutParams().width = 85;
    ImageThumbnails.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    ImageThumbnails.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    ImageThumbnails.setOnClickListener(this);


    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + imageName;
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
      Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 85, 85, true);
      ImageThumbnails.setImageBitmap(bmpCompressed);

    }

    ll.addView(ImageThumbnails);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should read those articles on the Android portal that explain exactly how to do it and provide the code:

Displaying bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Loading large bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: First of all I agree, it is better to load the `Bitmap` in the form you want to use it rather than load then rescale as a second operation. You should also be aware that bitmaos use system resources and should be `recycled` once you're done.  ie if you keep your original code you'll want to call `myBitmap.recycle()` in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to download each image individually and save it to disk (individually). Thats what I did for 30+ images for a Magazine App.

Comment: I did the same, but loading the thumbnails is too much memory (even when compressing like the article suggests).  the images i am loading are tiny (about 50 kb), and i still compress them to 85 by 85...but memory runs out still.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved with `lazy list adapter`. Try this example [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)